# JQuery Post request failing in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I'm doing a standard post using JQuery 1.4.4, not cross domain.

```
             $.post("http://localhost:8085/ComponentPreferences:ignoreContent?_="+new Date().getTime(), {mydata:bla}, function(xml) {
                          //do something
             });
```

This has suddenly stopped working on IE7 (works on all other browsers), the request is simply never sent (verified via Fiddler). It used to work fine on IE7 (as far as I am aware, nothing has changed :-) )

I've debugged the JQuery post method through to the ajax call and can see that it's getting as far as opening the socket (~ line 5912 on jQuery 1.4.4)

```
xhr.open(type, s.url, s.async);
```

The URL being passed in looks good, type is POST, async is true.

but this never returns. No error is reported. I've got all the security settings on IE7 at the minimum.

Any clues how to debug this further or what the problem might be?

Comment: Famous last words: "as far as I am aware, nothing has changed" :D

Answer (score 0):

try this make sure server is getting request

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url_,
        data: urlParams_,
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false,
        success: function(result_) {
            if (result_.length > 0 ){
                try{
                    result_ = $.parseJSON(result_);
                    result = result_;
                }catch (e){
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Request is never made. Fails on xhr.open(type, s.url, s.async); Confirmed by debugging the jQUery code.

Comment: what r u using servlet/jsp/java(framwork)? and try out once replacing URL with `url_` and alert the `result`

Comment: I'm not sure what the backend has to do with it, the request is not being made. I've confirmed this by using wireshark/fiddler/debugging the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

Add

$.support.cors = true;
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

for submitting ajax request to server