# How to use the POST method of JQuery in WP7's WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, jquery, silverlight-4.0

How to use the POST method of JQuery in a local webpage which added to a WebBrowser control in my windows phone 7 application?

I have added a WebBrowser control in my windows phone 7 application and let it Navigate to a local webpage which stored in the Isolate Memory. Now I want to add some JavaScript code to let the webpage could exchange data with the local Apache Server which is on my computer.

For example, I want that the webpage could call a function uses a post method when I click a button on the webpage which is showed in the WebBrowser control of my app.

I'm a new learner. If someone could post the code, it would be very nice! Thank you very much！

---

Added content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function submit_btn(){
        $("#customerName").val("it shows");
        alert("it happens");
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url:"http://127.0..0.1/test.php",
          data:{id:'10'},
          success:function(data){
            if(data.length > 0){
              try{
                $("#items").val(data);
              }catch(e){
                alert(e);
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
</script>
```

It works on local server, but didn't work on my WP7 app. 
It seemed to be limited by the Same Origin Policy or not. Because when I try to send a post request from my local machine to the local server which is a Apache Server, it was limited by the Same Origin Policy. However, it may be not the reason.
The code `$("#customerName").val("it shows");` worked, but `alert("it happens");` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing holds you back. Just include JQuery normally in your local web page and do your post. [JQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) supports Windows Phone 7. Example code on how to do the post can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069628/jquery-post-request-failing-in-ie-7/6070144#6070144).

Don't forget to set [`IsScriptEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.isscriptenabled%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to true on your `WebBrowser`!

Comment: Hi, Heinrich!thank you for your reply!
But it does not work! Please see that I added above.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure wp7 has `window.alert` defined? If not then it would throw an exception preventing the rest of your code from running. Try using `console.log( )` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure wp7 has windows.alert, even I think it has not. But Heinrich give me an example, the one use it.
I don't need windows.alert. I need to know how to use $.post or $.get, however other JQuery code works.